# MYSQL Double value rounding query

Tags: mysql

I have table which contains  double values stored in mysql database  ...I  need  to calculate the sum of three fields from three tables.
will the query select sum(r.columnname * (r.table2.columnname2/r3.columname1))  from table name.

where r,r1,r2 are table names.

columnname is the name of the column in the particular table concerned.all the column have double values in table .

will the above query give accurate value ..I am dealing with currencies in those  tables .

can i round and sum the values or else any other query is available for this condition

Comment: If those values are currencies, they should _not_ be doubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly that you want to round the sum, because it represents money, then you'll want to do this:

```
... ROUND( sumhere, 2 ) ...;
```

Comment: This will round  the total values for example if we get output as 1234.566667   .it gives as 1234.57. but i need to perform when calculating the sum for each individual record and then calculate so as answer could be correct .i think